# I need help with rel=canonical

Tags: seo, canonical-url

I have trouble understanding `rel="canonical"` the way Google wants me to implement it.

I have a job site that uses filters to show subsets of the total job list. Nothing fancy... normal stuff.

So if you go to `/jobs` you are able to paginate through all of them. You can then apply all sorts of filters like: `/jobs/new-york` or `/jobs?jobs_position_id=3` (I know this is a "bad" URL. I will change it to show actual words, but this does not change my canonical question).

Also there is a search like `/jobs?query=FOO` (with `&job_position_id=3` added with filters).

How should I apply `rel="canonical"` here? I tried some strategies, but I had the feeling Google didn't like it. Right now there is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very simple. If you have *two URLs* which display the *same content*, you need to use canonical URLs. Which URL is the canonical URL? The one *you want Google to list in its search results*?

In your example, you would have the main search result without the filters being your canonical URL. So `/jobs/new-york` or `/jobs?jobs_position_id=3` would be the canonical URL for `/jobs?jobs_position_id=3&query=FOO`.

Comment: But it is not the same. Every filter is displaying a subset of the complete list /jobs and every combination results in a different subset. So /jobs would be canonical for /jobs?query=FOO AND /jobs?job_position_id=3. By that /jobs would be canonical to every filtered subset combination?

Comment: If the filter is eliminating some results but leaving others then you probably don't want to use canonical URLs as the results are different. However, if there are a lot of only slightly different results with the filters enabled this runs the risk of being considered low quality content and then canonical URLs might be required.

Comment: This is the case! Should I then maybe tell google that it does not need to check out all combination?

Comment: I would do like in the example in my answer simply because it makes all of the content discoverable. Then if a user wants to filer out the content they can do so once they get to your website.